# How to display the image preview in react native app?

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, preview

may I know how to display the image preview in React Native app? In iOS I was able to display if it is a http url but in the Android platform I cannot view the image as shown in the screenshot below:

**The Running React Native App in Android:**

[image]

**The Image Preview in iOS platform:**

[image]

In the code the attachment field is equal to this.state.attachment so can see the http url but when I connect it with the Image the image preview is blank. However if I hard code the exact http url address in iOS it can show the image.

```
//in iOS this one can show the image but Android cannot
let Image_Http_URL = { uri : 'http://localhost:3000/api/containers/container/download/FMS-SiteIcon_v2.jpg'};

//this one is both cannot but in url can show the http url address
let Image_Http_URL = { uri : 'this.state.attachment' };

<Image
 style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
 source={Image_Http_URL}
/>

<FloatLabelTextInput
 onChangeText={(attachment) => {
 this.setState({attachment})
 }}
value={this.state.attachment}
editable={false}
placeholder="Attachment"
style={styles.input}/>
```

Please help and thanks.

Comment: `Image` component for both IOS/Android uses  the native component both side. And to image in this component there is one way for both. Debug your code and cross check everything.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg, you mean like this? <Image
              style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
              source={{ uri : 'http://localhost:3000/api/containers/container/download/FMS-SiteIcon_v2.jpg'}}
            /> I got put like this also cannot shown in Android.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.attachment` should not be enclosed in a string, try `{ uri : this.state.attachment };` or `{ uri : {this.state.attachment} };`